# NSMutableAttributedString hides part of a NSString - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode-string, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a NSString with this format:

```
<p>When: Every day except Monday at 11:45am

</p><p>Where: Main Pool</p><p><br></p><p>Get refreshed in the main pool during the warm sunny days whilst participating in our animation's fit activities. Enjoy our aqua fitness 6 times per week.<br></p>
```

I use this code to display the html attributes and also set a default font size and color:

```
NSMutableAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[self.Description dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

        __block BOOL found = NO;
        [attrStr beginEditing];
        [attrStr enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length) options:0 usingBlock:^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
            if (value) {
                UIFont *oldFont = (UIFont *)value;
                UIFont *newFont = [oldFont fontWithSize:16];
                [attrStr addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:newFont range:range];
                [attrStr addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                               value:[UIColor darkGrayColor]
                               range:range];

                found = YES;
            }
        }]; 
        [attrStr endEditing];


cell.descLbl.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Those words doesn't show up:

```
fitness 6 times per week.<br></p>
```

it only shows some weird dots-lines at the top of where the letters should be.

I believe the problem is when I change the String to unicode, the length of the String changes and so the range. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show me the output? because your code works perfectly on my side

Comment: @Priya https://scontent.fath2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/36367588_1305880409544861_6333541035913773056_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=cdd1337141a89e2bbcc92a131a7177b5&oe=5BAFDC34

Comment: Maybe for some reason it adds one more empty line, but I don't know why.

Comment: try `[cell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];` after you set attributed string

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: Try to add `[cell.descLbl.attributedText sizeToFit];` after `cell.descLbl.attributedText = attrStr;`

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSAttributedString' declares the selector 'sizeToFit'

Comment: What are the constraints for the label? Have you add this lines in viewDidLoad?`self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;
 self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`

Comment: Sorry @Student, it was `[cell.descLbl sizeToFit];`

Comment: The label is small, nothing to do with the encoding or the parsing. Also, if you use Debug Hierarchy View in XCode, is the label frame correct and goes out of bounds for the lower part, or is the cell auto dimension causing issue?

Comment: Yea you were right Larme. It was a height problem.